# Cannot GET cookie?

Tags: r, rvest, httr

If we visit [this](https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx) url in chrome, with devtools open, we can clearly see a cookie appear (in chrome developer tools -> 'application' -> 'cookies').

If we attempt the same thing using `httr::GET()`, we expect to see the cookie, but we do not:

```
library(httr)

r <- GET("https://aps.dac.gov.in/LUS/Public/Reports.aspx")
r$cookies
# [1] domain     flag       path       secure     expiration name       value     
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Why is this, and how can we retrieve the cookie (along with the page html) preferably using either `httr` and/or `rvest` (plus other suggestions but **without** using an actual browser, headless or otherwise, including selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the cookie doesn't actually get generated until the user submits the form (by opening chrome developer tools and watching 'application' -> 'cookies' before and after form submission, we see the cookie appear.

Note this can be emulated using chrome incognito (it won't have access to the cookies in regular chrome, so it can be tried repeatedly for demonstration purposes).

Comment: Did anyboady find a way to get the cookie and scrape the page? I tried `httr::set_cookies()` but I do not understand who to use it ...

Comment: @DominikVogel I couldn't even get the cookie in the first place for some reason. You could ask a new question with your example and link to this page

Comment: Already done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64391812/scrape-site-that-asks-for-cookies-consent-with-rvest